# Saving to a specific file format with SaveFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, savefiledialog

I'm using a picture box to edit an image, and a file save dialog to save the image.

The problem I'm having is that regardless of the file format I select, the file is saved as a bitmap. I did some research here and tried making some changes, but they're not working. The dialog box tries to save the file 5 times, and then fails. My feeling is that I'm not successfully getting the file format/file extension selected.

I'm trying a couple different methods, but they're not working. I've read here on stack overflow that I should be using (`Path.GetExtension(save.FileName)`), but the compiler rejects `Path.GetExtension` (Path does not exist in the current context). Here's my code, I'd appreciate if someone could point out where my mistake is located.

```
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Filter = "Bitmap files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF files (*.gif)|*.gif|PNG files (*.png)|*.png|TIF files (*.tif)|*.tif|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    save.FilterIndex = 4;
    save.RestoreDirectory = true;
    save.OverwritePrompt = true;
    save.ShowHelp = true;
    save.AddExtension = true;

    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && save.FilterIndex == 1)  
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK &&  save.FileName.Substring(save.FileName.Length - 4) == ".jpg") 
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && save.FileName.Substring(save.FileName.Length - 3) == "gif")
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && save.FileName.Substring(save.FileName.Length - 3) == "png") 
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && save.FileName.Substring(save.FileName.Length - 3) == "tif")
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
    else 
        MessageBox.Show("File Save Error."); 
}
```

Also, is there any way to access file save options in C# (for example, subsampling in jpg or dithering in gif)?

Thank you

Comment: Please clean up the code and debug it to see what's wrong. You test for `OK` 5 times when only 1 would be enough, check for the file's extension 5 times in three different ways Just check for OK once, get the filename once then check in your debugger what is its value. If you have a compiler error, just fix it by adding the missing namespaces or libraries. Just googling for `Path.GetExtension` will show which namespace to use. Besides, I think Visual Studio itself proposes a fix to add the namespace in a context menu

Comment: You are only checking the FilterIndex  one time. You need to check it for all branches!

Comment: Also: your `Substring()` is bogus, use `Path.GetExtension()`

Comment: also: you mean "else if", not just "if".

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos: I did not realize Path.GetExtension was a namespace issue. I've been taking an introductory C# class for 6 weeks, we haven't even dealt with Windows Forms and Controls, I'm going to miss things that are obvious to experienced users. Thank you for pointing it out. 
TaW: Yes, you are correct.  I was trying 3 different methods of testing for file extension, which is why I only used that one once.  You're always a huge help, thank you.    
DrKoch: Path.GetExtension worked, thank you.
Mike Nakis: Correct, I shouldn't be coding half asleep, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post what worked for whoever else comes along with the same question.  Thanks to everyone above for your help.

```
using system.IO;

SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

save.Filter = "Bitmap files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF files (*.gif)|*.gif|PNG files (*.png)|*.png|TIF files (*.tif)|*.tif|All files (*.*)|*.*";

save.FilterIndex = 2;

save.RestoreDirectory = true;

save.OverwritePrompt = true;

save.ShowHelp = true;

save.AddExtension = true;

if ((save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)) {
  if (Path.GetExtension(save.FileName).ToLower() == ".bmp") {
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
  }
  else if (Path.GetExtension(save.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg") {
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }
  else if (Path.GetExtension(save.FileName).ToLower() == ".gif") {
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
  }
  else if (Path.GetExtension(save.FileName).ToLower() == ".png") {
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  }
  else if (Path.GetExtension(save.FileName).ToLower() == ".tif") {
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("File Save Error.");
  }
}
```

For some reason, PNGs are saving slightly larger than TIFs, PNGs should be about 33% smaller, I suspect that's an issue with the Visual Studio PNG implementation. For anyone interested in truly small PNGs, there's an open source console app called PNGcrush.